# How to add toggle for changing number of products displayed on content-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add in a toggle or dropdown at the top of my product category which enables the user to change how many products are being displayed, at the moment it just defaults to 4.

What would be the best way to achieve this? So far I seem unable to even change the default number manually.

I am using the Woocommerce file content-product.php on the latest version of Woocommerce and have left it pretty much as stock.

Woocommerce do seem to suggest using the following code:

```
/**
 * Change number of products that are displayed per page (shop page)
 */
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {
  // $cols contains the current number of products per page based on the value stored on Options -> Reading
  // Return the number of products you wanna show per page.
  $cols = 9;
  return $cols;
}
```

However I have been unable to have any luck with this so far and am unsure what else to try.

Many thanks, George.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Where you have added this filter? I mean in which file? It needs to go in theme `functions.php`

Comment: Yes, I have already tried adding the code in to functions.php, sadly though it didn't work.